# SymPy Plot Resolution

Tags: python-3.x, plot, sympy

I just recently started learning Python (Platform: Python 3.7) for my Signal processing and communications class and so far it has been great. However, I'm having issues reproducing the same resolutional quality that's achievable with MatPlotLib and linspace (shown in the code below) when using the SymPy library. I was wondering if there is any way of achieving the same resolution?

I understand that SymPy works off the MatPlotLib library, on the back-end, but is limited in how much it actually uses. I tried adding sampling rates to the time-domain limits in the sym.plot call, like you can do with linspace, but that doesn't work. Is there anyway to call the linspace function prior to plotting, to improve the plot's resolution, or even without using linspace?

Step 1 shows the necessary plots, using MatPlotLib. Step 2 shows the code I'm trying to develop to produce the same results, but the quality of the waveform is nowhere near the same as Step 1.

```
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Step 1 & Section Identifiers
fc, fm = 10**9,10**6
wc, wm, Ac, Am = 2*np.pi*fc, 2*np.pi*fm, 8, 2


# Carrier Signal Plot
t = np.linspace(0, 5/fc, 500)
ct = Ac*np.cos(wc*t)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('c(t)')
plt.plot(t,ct)
plt.show()

# Step 2 & Section Identifiers
t = sym.Symbol('t')
fc, fm = 10**7, 10**4
wc, wm = 2*sym.pi*fc, 2*sym.pi*fm

# Carrier Plot
ct = Ac*sym.cos(wc*t)
sym.plot(ct, (t, 0, 5/fc), ylabel = "C(t)")
```

**Edit**
I Found that I could turn off adaptive sampling and manually specifying the number of data points, to smooth out the signal. I have added the edited line(s) necessary to show this!

```
sym.plot(ct, (t, 0, 5/fc), ylabel = "C(t)", adaptive = False, nb_of_points = 500)
```